# Rgd htaccess on rewrite multiple query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Below is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /manage/member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /manage/member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2&sub_action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /manage/member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2&sub_action=$3&sub_id=$4 [L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```

I got this $_GET on my first few lines

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sub_action = $_GET['sub_action'];
```

If i send in a url like

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/manage/member/edit/5
```

It can get the action as edit and id as 5

But if I send in

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/manage/member/edit/5/permission
```

It is unable to retrieve the sub_action as permission. what should i do to get it working

It retrieve 5 as the $1 and permission as the $2 and $3 is null.

What .htaccess should I put in to allow $3 and $4 to be null or value yet able retrieve via $_GET when they got value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rules like this in `/manage/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manage/

# skip rewrite rules for all files and directories    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2&sub_action=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ member/index.php?action=$1&id=$2&sub_action=$3&sub_id=$4 [L,QSA]


# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: +1, I like your flow for the conditional logic, a bit easier than the `S` I've been playing with.

Comment: Thanks @zx81, yes keeping things simple helps. We just need to keep this thing in our mind that rewrite rules are applied top to bottom and are executed in a loop.